# HighCharts Multiseries binding

Tags: c#, json, highcharts

I've developed High chart graph for single series but not able to bind multiple series.

My requirement is like as below

I've check box list and contains as below and when user selects multiple checkbox and click on load button high charts will display what ever he selected.

TYPE A

TYPE B

TYPE C

TYPE D
........
TYPE Z

I'm able to done for one check box only but i'm not sure how to code for multiple selections and display in high charts.

I'm new to high charts and anybody help would be really appreciated.

My Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

            chart: {

                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'spline',
                zoomType: 'x',
                spacingRight: 50

            },

            title: {
                text: 'Sample Spline Chart',

                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
            text: document.ontouchstart === undefined ?
                'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in' :
                'Pinch the chart to zoom in',
                 x: -20
             },

            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                day: '%e %b %y',
                minute: '%l%M<br>%p'

               }
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                text: 'Values'
                },
             min: 0
            },
            series: [{

                name: 'Value',
                data: <%= chartData1%>


           }]

        });

    });


</script>
```

C# code:

```
protected void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    selectedLists.Clear();

    foreach (ListItem item in chkboxTypes.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected == true)
        {
            var selected = item.Text.Split(',');

            selectedLists.Add(selected[0]);
        }
    }

    foreach (var item in selectedLists)
    {
        typeID = item;

        var fromdate = fromdatepicker.Value;

        var todate = todatepicker.Value;

        var dsSql = string.Format(@"SELECT START_DATETIME, VALUE FROM XXXXX WHERE  TYPE_ID = '{0}' AND START_DATETIME >= '{1} 00:00' AND END_DATETIME <= '{2} 23:59' ORDER BY START_DATETIME ASC", typeID, fromdate, todate);

        var database = new Database(dbstring, "System.Data.SqlClient");
        database.CommandTimeout = 3600;
        var dataSourcesAttributes = database.Fetch<DataPoint>(dsSql);


        var chkboxData = string.Empty;

        if (dataSourcesAttributes.Count > 0)
        {

            foreach (var data in dataSourcesAttributes)
            {
                listDimensionalValues.Add(Tuple.Create(data.AppliesToDateTime, data.Value));

                JavaScriptSerializer serializeData = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var Validdata = serializeData.Serialize(listDimensionalValues.ToArray());

                chkboxData = Properdata(Validdata);
            }
            chartData1 = chkboxData;
        }
        else
        {

            lblError.Visible = true;
            lblError.Text = databasevalue + " There is no data available for this Type or please select different dates";

        }
    }

}
```

ChartData 1 string

```
 public string chartData1 { get; set; }
```

Please any suggestions or help mates

Comment: In multiple series it should be series: [{

                name: 'Value',
                data: <%= chartData1%>


           },{

                name: 'Value2',
                data: <%= chartData2%>


           }]

Comment: @SebastianBochan Thanks for your reply mate. Imagine if i got 10 names and 10 chartdata2 so I can't add like this right? I mean its not a good idea to add like this mate..is there any other way I can bind?

Comment: You can prepare your data in preprocessing in the loop, and push object into one array. Then in highcharts confgiuation use    series: myOwnSeriesArray which kept all data.

Comment: @SebastianBochan Thanks mate for your suggestion. I'm really new to json arrays. Is there any links i can refer to ?

Comment: I mean call function in your c# scrpit, push to array (according to the highscharts sturcutre) and then use in highcharts. It is only parsing data in your script.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in two ways.

1.first load all the series and then hide the unchecked ones using

```
chart.series[index].hide();
```

and when the user checks the check boxes bring them into view using

```
chart.series[index].show();
```

this can be done only when the data for all the series is available with you.

example fiddle for show/hide http://jsfiddle.net/JACDP/

2.add or remove series on the fly.

first load the chart with default series.

when user checks a new check box add a series using

```
chart.addSeries({
name: ,
data: [],
})
```

example for add series : http://jsfiddle.net/9JzLN/
when unchecked use

```
chart.series[index].remove();
```

example for remove series http://jsfiddle.net/ArkxY/

hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try this mate. Somebody told yesterday just create array of arrays with json object.